# Apache Tomac Web Server and LOG4J Framework

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, service, log4j

I am new to Web Service and LAMP Stack.Currently I am working on a Web Application.It is a PHP Based Application that uses Apache Tomcat Web Server 8.0.26 ,MySQL Database ad Linux operating system(LAMP Stack).It has Web Services  in Spring.
Following are the issues I am facing with the Application:-

1) Responses are slow over a period of few weeks from a web service hosted on tomcat.

**Temporary Solution**:-*The problem is solved when we restart the Web Server.*

2) What are the tools we can use to monitor tomcat / performance ?

Regards

Kaustubh

Answer (score 1):

Take the dump of heap usage before and after of slow down and analyze. And also check your connection pooling with the database, check whether logs are getting rotated properly or not, check the number of active sessions in tomcat admin console.

Comment: Hi,
I think there is some problem with connection pooling.Will try and check it out.However I have come with other issue:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717736/error-server-tomcat-v8-0-server-at-localhost-was-unable-to-start-within-45-seco